# Build program using library and headers installed in a conda environment

Tags: conda

I have OpenCV 3.2.0 installed in a conda environment. I would like to use it to build an application, but I'm not sure if conda already provides a tool to automatically handle which dependencies are visible considering the active environment.

For instance, the OpenCV library is in the following paths:

```
/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2
/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/libopencv_optflow.so.3.2
/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib/libopencv_freetype.so.3.2
...
```

and headers are at:

```
/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/include/opencv2/core.hpp
/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/include/opencv2/ximgproc.hpp
...
```

I can resolve this by passing the flags directly using

```
-I/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/include/ -L/home/me/anaconda2/envs/python3/lib
```

or

```
LDFLAGS="-L/home/me/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/home/me/local/include" make
```

But, is this the best way? I saw [references](https://conda.io/docs/building/shared-libraries.html) to [`conda build`](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/d1rn9KPIniM), but seeing the docs, it seems more suited to build conda packages.

Comment: Indeed, conda build is for building conda packages. You can have environment variables set automatically when you activate an environment, see here: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#saved-environment-variables

Comment: It seems conda sets the `$LIBRARY_PATH` variable automatically. See `anaconda2/envs/<ENV>/etc/conda/activate.d/pygpu_vars.sh`. I recently noticed that I was able to compile my program using OpenCV from my conda. I thought I was using the system's library, but it wasn't working until I `activate`d the environment.

Comment: Actually, I was checking my other environments and they are empty; this is not created automatically in each environment. This script probably was created by a package I installed, following the convention you suggested in your comment, @darthbith. I think I got lucky! `:)` 
Would you like to post your comment as an answer and include `LIBRARY_PATH` as an example? This is what did it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `conda build` is for building conda packages. You can have environment variables set automatically when you activate an environment, see here: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#saved-environment-variables

As you noted,

> It seems conda sets the `$LIBRARY_PATH` variable automatically. See `anaconda2/envs/<ENV>/etc/conda/activate.d/pygpu_vars.sh`. I recently noticed that I was able to compile my program using OpenCV from my conda. I thought I was using the system's library, but it wasn't working until I `activate`d the environment.

It is likely that a package created that script (maybe the `pygpu` package?) such that when you activate the environment, the proper variables are set to use the libraries provided with the package. It is not guaranteed that all packages will do this though...

---

Example based on `envs/python3/etc/conda/activate.d/pygpu_vars.sh`:

```
export CPATH_PYGPU_BACKUP="$CPATH"
export CPATH=anaconda2/envs/python3/include:"$CPATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP="$LIBRARY_PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH=anaconda2/envs/python3/lib:"$LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=anaconda2/envs/python3/lib:"$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Deactivate script at `envs/python3/etc/conda/deactivate.d/pygpu_vars.sh`:

```
export CPATH="$CPATH_PYGPU_BACKUP"
unset CPATH_PYGPU_BACKUP
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP"
unset LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP"
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH_PYGPU_BACKUP
```