# How to install Python debug symbols and libraries via miniconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, cpython

I have created a new Python 3.8 environment using:

```
conda create -n myproj python=3.8
```

But the installed Python version has no debug symbols and libraries for CPython included. I know how to install them with the normal installer but is there any way to install them via miniconda?
Right now there are only the *.lib files for the release build included but the *_d.lib files for a debug build are missing. Here are 2 Screenshots for comparison.

A installation via normal installer (including the libs) looks like this:
[image: Python 3.11 Installation with Debug Symbols and Libraries]

A Python Installation via miniconda:
[image: Python 3.8 Installation via Miniconda, Debug symbols and libs are missing]

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: [What should I put in my conda envirnment file to install python-dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58436055/11082165) and [Build program using library and headers installed in a conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44793143/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270 My problem is simply that everything only for the release build is included. The *_d.lib files for example are missing from the "libs" folder. This questions i have already checked and there was nothing to solve my problem.

Comment: That sounds like useful information that should be included in the question with an [edit]. Could you please clarify exactly what is present and what is missing?